# 'app-navbar' not rendering after running `ng add @angular/material`

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, material-design

I'm trying to add Material [multi-selection](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection) component to my angular+ts website.

I've added the lines to my app.module.ts
[image]

And to my html and ts.

[image]

[image]

I ran `ng add @angular/material`

I try to `ng serve` but I still get an errors about angular component that used to render a moment ago.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-navbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:21:16
    21   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Even thought navbar is imported (and used to work):
[image]

Comment: the error states that the issue is in `app.component.html`, the navbar component seems not to be part of app module..

Comment: Thanks, but it is. See my updated attachment. Please

Comment: did you add `NavbarComponent` in `declarations` of app.module.ts